# TextView Check if ellipsized doesn't work with android:autoLink="web"

Tags: android, textview

Usually this is how I check if my TextViews have been ellipsized:

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = description_detail.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        Layout l = description_detail.getLayout();

        if (l != null) {
            int lines = l.getLineCount();
            Log.e("lineCount=", String.valueOf(lines));
            Log.e("getEllipsisCount=", String.valueOf(l.getEllipsisCount(lines - 1)));

            if (lines > 0)
                if (l.getEllipsisCount(lines - 1) > 0)
                //ELLIPSIZED
        }
    }
});
```

As soon as I add

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

to my TextView, it doesn't work anymore.

I do not understand why this is the case. Any ideas?

Edit:

```
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/description_detail"
      android:layout_width="250dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:autoLink="web"
      android:maxLines="3"
      android:text=""
      android:textColor="@color/hostGrey"
      android:textSize="16dp" />
```

So whenever the lines count of my TextBox is greater than 3, it's being ellipsized.

**Debugging results:**

With autolink active:

```
lines == 107
l.getEllipsisCount(lines - 1) == 0
```

Without autolink:

```
lines == 3
l.getEllipsisCount(lines - 1) == 1
```

Comment: have you tried to debug it? how is it not working ? does it return 0

Comment: Yes. I edited my post so you can see the results

Comment: any workaround?